# Criar virtualhost no windows (apache no ubuntu)

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

Estou tentando configurar o meu `apache` para acessar uma pasta que se encontra no meu `HD` com `windows`, tenho 2 `hds` na máquina, um roda o `ubuntu` e o outro o `windows`.

O `apache` já esta instalado, inclusive eu já criei o arquivo:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/vip.localhost.conf
```

Adicionei as linhas:

```
   ServerName vip.localhost
   ServerAlias vip.localhost
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /media/name/2E4C85684C852BA1/development
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log
```

E também fiz a alteração no arquivo de `hosts`, mas quando eu tento acessar `vip.localhsot` eu recebo o código:

> 403 Forbiden

No caso diz que eu não tenho acesso a esse diretório.

Alguém tem ideia do que tenho que fazer? Será que preciso montar uma pasta no `ubuntu` para ele conseguir acessar meus arquivos? Se sim como faço?

Comment: 403 significa acesso negado, existe condições de fornecer as permissões necessárias para essa pasta?

Comment: Provável causa é a falta da permissão de acesso que está na resposta do Ricardo (configurada na tag Directory). Estranhei a falta de tags na configuração, mas não sei como está a estrutura de includes, talvez tenham sido omitidas apenas para postar aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro de tudo, verifique se na montagem do seu HD do Windows, **ele possui permissão de leitura e escrita** para o usuário `www-data`, que é o usuário que o Apache roda no Ubuntu.

Depois, crie um arquivo em `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/seuvhost.conf` e o conteúdo tem que ser parecido com esse aqui (para Apache 2.4.X):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /media/name/2E4C85684C852BA1/development
    ServerName yourserver.example.com

    <Directory /media/name/2E4C85684C852BA1/development>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Feito isso, habilite esse novo VirtualHost com o comando:

```
sudo a2ensite seuvhost
```

E reinicie o Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Outro solução é Ter um servidor completo com o XAMPP(lampp). 
só instalar o [xampp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/)

Dai é só iniciar o servidor e fazer as configurações no VirtualHost.